# Check if style is declared in child theme from within parent theme. if so, use that style in parent theme

Tags: themes, child-theme

Wondering if there is a way to check if a scss style is declared in a child theme. If it is then i would like to use that style inside its parent theme. Does something like this exist?

Comment: I suppose in theory you could include SCSS files from a child theme directory from within your parent theme — but because SCSS has to be compiled, it wouldn’t work in operation on a live site.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.